# Http-request-based health check on socket io connection

Tags: socket.io, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Google Cloud Platform requires to create http healthchecker for each Load Balancer. If i have an instance (server), which exposes only socket.io connection gateway, then what address should my healthchecker use? I hope, i don't have to explicitly expose specific address for `GET` request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP health checks indeed perform GET requests to the configured path, but, depending on your load balancer and/or your traffic, HTTP health checks are not required.

I will make a resume that will be valid for everyone, therefore depending on your traffic:

- HTTP: then you should use [HTTP Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/) that it is a global resource and requires a [health check](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks) that could be HTTP(S), SSL or TCP.
  You would not need to expose any new port or address since you could
  simply use the service already running on your instance.
- TCP and the port should be one of 25, 43, 110, 143, 195, 443, 465, 587, 700, 993, 995, 1883, 5222: you can use [TCP Proxy Load 
  Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/tcp-ssl/tcp-proxy#overview) that is global and you will require a [health check](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks) that could be HTTP(S), SSL or TCP.
  You would not need to expose any new port or address since you could
  simply use the service already running on your instance.
- TCP or UDP with a custom port: you can deploy a 
  [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/), it is regional and it does not require a
  health check.
  [Legacy HTTP Health checks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#legacy_health_checks)  only are supported.
  You can decide to carry on without health checks that is not really
  recommended in production since you might lose portion of the traffic
  or to run a small webserver in order to answer the requests